# Binary search algorithm with string array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary

The program is supposed to search for a name in a string array. Originally, the program was adapted to the int data type but changed to string. I tried to modify the code to make it run and it does, but I do not get the correct output. There is something wrong with my binary search function. My binary search function has not been correctly edited to suit the change in data type from int to string. It will not function since I have strings in the array instead of int which it was originally created for. Everything else seems to work correctly.

This is the output I get.

> Please enter an employee's name: **Looney**
>
> That name does that exist in the array.

Technically, I am supposed to get the message that it exists and what position it does.

```
// This program demonstrates the binarySearch function, which
// performs a binary search on an integer array.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

// Function prototype
void sortArray(string [], int); 
int binarySearch(string [], int, string);
const int SIZE = 20;

int main()
{
    // Defined array 
    const int NUM_NAMES = 20;
    string names[NUM_NAMES] = {"Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Allen, Jim",
                               "Griffin, Jim", "Stamey, Marty", "Rose, Geri",
                               "Taylor, Terri", "Johnson, Jill", "Allison, Jeff",
                               "Looney, Joe", "Wolfe, Bill", "James, Jean",
                               "Weaver, Jim", "Pore, Bob", "Rutherford, Greg",
                               "Javens, Renee", "Harrison, Rose", "Setzer, Cathy",
                               "Pike, Gordon", "Holland, Beth" };

    // Variables 
    string empName; 
    int results;  

    // Sort array first
    sortArray(names, NUM_NAMES); 

    // Prompt for user input to enter an employee name 
    cout << "Please enter an employee's name: "; 
    getline(cin, empName); 

    // Search for name
    results = binarySearch(names, NUM_NAMES, empName); 

    // If results contains -1 the name was not found.
    if (results == -1)
        cout << "That name does not exist in the array.\n";
    else
    {
        // Otherwise results contains the subscript of
        // the specified employee ID in the array.
        cout << "That name is found at element " << results;
        cout << " in the array.\n";
    }

    system("PAUSE"); 

    return 0;
}

//**************************************************************
// Definition of function sortArray.                           *
// This function performs an ascending order selection sort on *
// array. size is the number of elements in the array.         *
//**************************************************************
void sortArray(string names[], int size)
{
    int startScan, minIndex; 
    string minValue;

    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = names[startScan];
        for(int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if (names[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = names[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        names[minIndex] = names[startScan];
        names[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}

//***************************************************************
// The binarySearch function performs a binary search on an     *
// integer array. array, which has a maximum of size elements,  *
// is searched for the number stored in value. If the number is *
// found, its array subscript is returned. Otherwise, -1 is     *
// returned indicating the value was not in the array.          *
//***************************************************************
int binarySearch(string names[], int size, string value)
{
    int first = 0,             // First array element
        last = size - 1,       // Last array element
        middle,                // Mid point of search
        position = -1;         // Position of search value
    bool found = false;        // Flag

    while (!found && first <= last)
    {
        middle = (first + last) / 2;     // Calculate mid point
        if (names[middle] == value)      // If value is found at mid
        {
            found = true;
            position = middle;
        }
        else if (names[middle] > value)  // If value is in lower half
            last = middle - 1;
        else
            first = middle + 1;           // If value is in upper half
    }
    return position;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly ("*There is something wrong with my binary search function*" is very broad).

Comment: Why don't you use `std::sort` and `std::binary_search`?

Comment: @MohitJain Good suggestion. I'm not sure... maybe because binary_search only returns bool and not the position for some f***ing reason ;)  I'm not the only one who wonders about it btw ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495744/why-does-stdbinary-search-return-bool ...But I guess lower_bound could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because name `Looney` does not exist in the array.

You should input `Looney, Joe` to get the expected output.

Input is bad, otherwise your implementation appear good.